# CircleCI Extension Package Build/Deploy Problem

Tags: managed-extension, circleci

I have an extension package based on two other base packages.  I am trying to set up continuous integration with CircleCI.  The two base packages install fine but the deploy of the extension package source blows up.  It seems like the deploy does not have access to the installed a packages for some reason.

The relevant section of the config.yml file:

```
    echo 'Grant/Create/Push'
    sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid $HUB_CONSUMER_KEY --jwtkeyfile .circleci/server.key --username $HUB_SFDC_USER --setdefaultdevhubusername -a hub            
    sfdx force:org:create -s -f .circleci/project-scratch-def.json -a circle_build_$CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM -d 1 -w 30
    # install TMS 7.6.8 and Magnolia
    sfdx force:package:install --package 04t5b000001yxHb -k xxxxxx--noprompt -w 30
    echo 'TMS Installed'            
    sfdx force:package:install --package 04t3b000000ydgO --noprompt -w 30
    echo 'Accounting Seed Installed'
    sfdx force:package:installed:list -u circle_build_$CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM
    # push the code and inactive duplicate rules
    sfdx force:source:push -u circle_build_$CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM -w 30
```

From the logs the two package installations seem to work fine, BUT then the deploy of source does not seem to have access to components in the base packages:

```
Waiting for the package install request to complete. Status = IN_PROGRESS
Successfully installed package [04t5b000001yxHb]
TMS Installed
....
Successfully installed package [04t3b000000ydgO]
Accounting Seed Installed
=== Installed Package Versions [2]
ID                  Package ID          Package Name                     Namespace  Package Version ID  Version Name         Version
──────────────────  ──────────────────  ───────────────────────────────  ─────────  ──────────────────  ───────────────────  ─────────
0A31F000000LV97SAG  033C0000000HJMxIAO  Accounting Seed Financial Suite  AcctSeed   04t3b000000ydgOAAQ  Maghome              3.105.4.2
0A31F000000LV6hSAG  033j00000005iAVAAY  TMS                              rtms       04t5b000001yxHbAAI  Spring 2022 - 7.6.8  7.6.8.1
*** Pushing with SOAP API v54.0 ***
DEPLOY PROGRESS | ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ | 0/583 ComponentsDEPLOY PROGRESS | █████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ | 255/583 ComponentsDEPLOY PROGRESS | ██████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ | 258/583 ComponentsDEPLOY PROGRESS | ███████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ | 281/583 ComponentsDEPLOY PROGRESS | ███████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ | 284/583 ComponentsDEPLOY PROGRESS | ████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ | 352/583 ComponentsDEPLOY PROGRESS | ██████████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░ | 430/583 ComponentsDEPLOY PROGRESS | ██████████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░ | 436/583 ComponentsDEPLOY PROGRESS | ██████████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░ | 441/583 ComponentsDEPLOY PROGRESS | ██████████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░ | 443/583 ComponentsDEPLOY PROGRESS | ████████████████████████████████░░░░░░░░ | 473/583 ComponentsDEPLOY PROGRESS | █████████████████████████████████░░░░░░░ | 475/583 ComponentsDEPLOY PROGRESS | ████████████████████████████████████████ | 428/428 Components

=== Component Failures [226]
Type   Name                                                                     Problem
─────  ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Error  ACHEmailRemittanceBatchJob                                               Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation:
                                                                                 Class ACHRemittanceControllerBase : Variable does not exist: Payment_Method__c (87:87)
Error  ACHRemittanceControllerBase                                              Variable does not exist: Batch_Type__c (151:61)
Error  ACHRemittanceControllerBase                                              Variable does not exist: Alternate_Payee__c (99:164)
Error  ACHRemittanceControllerBase                                              Variable does not exist: Alternate_Payee__c (98:50)
Error  ACHRemittanceControllerBase                                              Variable does not exist: Payment_Method__c (87:87)  etc...
```

Question:  What else has to happen for the base packages to be visible to the subsequent deployment of source?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh - Stupid human trick.  I was missing a global value set entry in my package contents which was causing the deploy error.  Thanks for trying to help, Jason.  My bad.

Comment: No worries.  It had the feeling of some simple issue causing complex results ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the code in the extension package is trying to access an object from one of the installed packages, it needs to use the namespace prefix of the package.  So, that would be AcctSeed__Payment_Method__c.

You should be able to reproduce this same thing from outside of CircleCI which would help eliminate it as a potential source of issues.  The error you're getting is coming from the Metadata API and CircleCI is just relaying it to you.

Comment: Thanks, Jason.  The Payment_Method__c field is (new) in the extension package itself, so no namespace is needed.  I feel like the package(s) are invisible to the deploying process and it has something to do with CRUD or permission sets.  The second package has permission set licenses.  I wonder if they have any impact on the visibility of code.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting.  Are Batch_Type__c and Alternate_Payee__c also objects in the extension package?  If so, all the error messages point to those objects being the issue.  It's possible the permission set licenses are an issue, but in that case I'd expect the error to be calling out objects from the base packages rather than the extension.  You could try this out in a scratch org pretty easily locally to allow you to examine the state of the org.  The deployment is going to be using your admin user in the scratch org, the same as in CircleCI.